# Whois with a list of domain names but got error "No whois server is known for this kind of object

Tags: linux, bash, whois

I got the error message  "No whois server is known for this kind of object." When I had my script run.

```
#!/bin/bash

domain_list="input.txt"
while read line
do
        name=$line
        echo $name
        whois $name
        sleep 2
done < input.txt
```

But if I check each line of the input.txt individually as follow it worked !!
`whois exmaple.com`

- UPDATE ANSWER

```
while IFS=$' \t\r\n' read -r line
```

Comment: Most likely `input.txt` contains DOS `CRLF` line endings rather than 'nix `LF`, so the `read` command reads the `CR` character as well and it creates invalid domain names. Try `while IFS=$' \t\r\n' read -r line`

Comment: To verify what LéaGris suspected, have a look at `xxd input.txt`.